# Text Based Game- Why won't it move directions?

Tags: python

I am creating a text based game in my intro to Python Scripting game. I have to create pseudocode as well to assist in the game development. I feel like I am close but when I test it, it won't let me move from room to room. My code does not identify any errors, but no matter what direction I prompt, it stays in my first room: Mail Room.

> Scenario: You work for a small company that creates text-based games. You have been asked to pitch an idea to your team for a text-based adventure game with a theme and environment of your choice. Your game must include different rooms, items, and a villain. The basic gameplay will require the player to move between different rooms to gather all of the items. A player wins the game by collecting all the items before encountering the villain. The player will have two options for commands in the game: moving to a different room, and getting an item from the room they are in. Movement between rooms happens in four simple directions: North, South, East, and West.
>
> You must include the designs for your game as a part of your idea pitch. Specifically, you have been asked to provide a map that displays the different rooms and items. You have also been asked to use pseudocode or flowcharts to design code for moving between rooms and getting items. If your pitch gets approved, these designs will help your team members understand the pitch, and will help the team develop the game in the future.

```
import time

# A dictionary for the Hacker text game

# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.

    rooms = {
    'Mail Room': {'South': 'Main Clinic', 'East': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Pager'}, # First Room
    'Main Clinic': {'North': 'Mail Room', 'item': 'Printer', 'South': 'Billing Office', 'item': 'Laptop', 'East': 'Doctor Office', 'item': 'Phone', 'West': 'Accounting', 'item': 'Tablet'},
    'Doctor Office': {'North': 'Break Room', 'item': 'Coffee Machine', 'West': 'Main Clinic'},
    'Billing Office': {'East': 'IT Office'},
    'IT Office': {'West': 'Billing Office'} #Last Room
}

    \#defining the game instructions
    def introduction():
    print('')
    print('\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*Hacker Text Adventure Game \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\\n')
    print('***')
    print('\\nThere are 8 rooms to move between and 6 items to pick up\\n')
    print('in order to complete your adventure.\\n')
    print('Directions: You can go North, South, East, or West\\n')
    print('to navigate between rooms. If the room has an item\\n')
    print('it will be picked up and added to your inventory.\\n')
    print('You can also type exit to leave the game. Good Luck!\\n')
    print('***\\n\\n')

# Defining player status, prints

    def player_status():
    print('=========================================')
    print('\\nYou are currently in the {}'.format(currentRoom))
    print('\\nYour current inventory: {}'.format(inventory))
    \#print('You see a {}'.format(currentItem))
    print('\\n=========================================')
    print('\\n')

# Inventory list to hold inventory as it's added in each room

    inventory = \[\]

    user_item = ''

# defining Inventory carried to add to inventory list

    def game(item):
    \#user_item = input('')

    if item in inventory:  # use in operator to check membership
        print("you already have this")
        print(" ".join(inventory))
    
    elif item not in inventory:
        print('You see a', item)
        print('Would you like to pick it up? \n')
        user_item = input('')
        if user_item == 'Y':
            print('item has been added\n')
            inventory.append(item)
        else:
            print('You leave the item behind.')
    #else:
        #print("You see a", item)
        #print("and you pick it up, it has been added to inventory")
        #inventory.append(item)
        #print(" ".join(inventory))

# Current Room, starts off in Mail Room

currentRoom = 'Mail Room'

# Players Move

player_move = ''

# Calling the Introduction function

introduction()

# While Loop for moving between rooms

while True:
player_status()

    player_move = input('Enter a move: \n')
    
    if player_move == 'Exit':
        print('Thanks for playing.')
        # break statement for exiting
        break
    
    if player_move in rooms[currentRoom]:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][player_move]
    
        addItem = input(' \n')
    
        if 'item' in rooms[currentRoom]:
            game(rooms[currentRoom]['item'])
    
        #if/else statements with break statement for final room/finishing the game
        if currentRoom == 'IT Office':
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('\n***********************     Congratulations!     ***********************')
                print('\n************************************************************************')
                print('\nYou have made it to the IT Office with all of the items to ')
                print('stop the hacker and recover the information.\n')
                print('You have completed your mission. You are a Hero to your company!\n')
                print('*************************************************************************\n')
                print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Thanks for playing! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n\n')
                break
    
            else:
                print('\n################## You Failed! #####################')
                print('\n####################################################')
                print('\nYou are missing items needed to stop the hacker')
                print('& the sensitive information is at risk. All of your')
                print('companies data is gone. Time to polish your resume.')
                print('\n####################################################\n')
                print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Please play again @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')
                break
    
    # else statement for input validation/invalid move
        else:
                print('\nYou walk in to a wall, try again.\n')
```

Comment: First you must fix the indentation of the code and remove some ``\`` where they don't belong.

Comment: Try stepping it through a debugger, line by line, and inspect the variables. This will help you identify where the problem is and also help you get a better understanding of the program. Use the built-in debugger of your IDE or an online one ([pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=edit) is a good one as it provide good visualization as well).

Comment: @mkrieger1 The backslashes were almost certainly added by the New Question Wizard, it's a common issue.

Comment: When you type the direction, do you use the correct capitalization?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can fix:

1. Fix indentation, remove `\` it breaks your code
2. You have duplicated key `item` in `rooms` variable. It's not allowed for `dict` data type. Use list for storing multiple `items`. For simplicity I've made one item per one room
3. For readability sake you can move all text from `print` function to constants, e.g.: `INTRODUCTION`, `WIN`, `LOOSE`

Code:

```
ROOMS = {
    'Mail Room': {'South': 'Main Clinic', 'East': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Pager'},  # First Room
    'Main Clinic': {'North': 'Mail Room', 'South': 'Billing Office', 'East': 'Doctor Office', 'item': 'Printer'},
    'Doctor Office': {'North': 'Break Room', 'West': 'Main Clinic', 'item': 'Coffee Machine'},
    'Billing Office': {'East': 'IT Office', 'item': 'Laptop'},
    'IT Office': {'West': 'Billing Office'}  # Last Room
}

INTRODUCTION = r'''\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* Hacker Text Adventure Game \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
There are 5 rooms to move between and 4 items to pick up
in order to complete your adventure.
Directions: You can go North, South, East, or West
to navigate between rooms. If the room has an item
it will be picked up and added to your inventory.
You can also type exit to leave the game. Good Luck!'''

WIN = '''***********************     Congratulations!     ***********************
************************************************************************
You have made it to the IT Office with all of the items to
stop the hacker and recover the information.
You have completed your mission. You are a Hero to your company!
*************************************************************************
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Thanks for playing! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'''

LOOSE = '''################## You Failed! #####################
####################################################
You are missing items needed to stop the hacker
& the sensitive information is at risk. All of your
companies data is gone. Time to polish your resume.
####################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Please play again @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'''

current_room = 'Mail Room'
inventory = []

print(INTRODUCTION)
while True:

    if current_room == 'IT Office':
        if len(inventory) == 4:
            print(WIN)
        else:
            print(LOOSE)
        break

    print('=========================================')
    print(f'You are currently in the {current_room}')
    print(f'Your current inventory: {inventory}')
    item = ROOMS[current_room].get('item')
    if item:
        print(f'You see a {item}')
        action = input('Would you like to pick it up [Y/N]? ').lower()
        if action == 'y':
            print(f'{item} has been added')
            inventory.append(item)
            del ROOMS[current_room]['item']
        else:
            print('You leave the item behind.')

    print(f'You can walk to: {[r for r in ROOMS[current_room].keys() if r != 'item']}')
    print('=========================================')

    move = input('Enter a move: ').capitalize()
    new_room = ROOMS[current_room].get(move)
    if new_room:
        current_room = new_room
    elif move == 'exit':
        print('Thanks for playing.')
        break
    else:
        print('You walk in to a wall, try again.')
```

Sample output:

```
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* Hacker Text Adventure Game \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
There are 5 rooms to move between and 4 items to pick up
in order to complete your adventure.
Directions: You can go North, South, East, or West
to navigate between rooms. If the room has an item
it will be picked up and added to your inventory.
You can also type exit to leave the game. Good Luck!
=========================================
You are currently in the Mail Room
Your current inventory: []
You see a Pager
Would you like to pick it up [Y/N]? Y
Pager has been added
You can walk to: ['South', 'East']
=========================================
Enter a move: South
=========================================
You are currently in the Main Clinic
Your current inventory: ['Pager']
You see a Printer
Would you like to pick it up [Y/N]? N
You leave the item behind.
You can walk to: ['North', 'South', 'East']
=========================================
```